# how to use single core for each collection in solr cloud?

Tags: solr, solrcloud

Is there any way in solr cloud to keep one collection's data in place so that all indexing and search queries are triggered to that collection only. I am facing an issue in solr join queries.
lets say I have a document,

```
{
        "form_object_id":"a5ec120cd61e41a2a8f05b01edbb8a89",
        "app_id":2400,
        "id":"formobj_a5ec120cd61e41a2a8f05b01edbb8a89_account_1704",
        "account_id":1704,
        "location_gps_value":"[]",
        "title":"Mumbai",
        "formobject_created_at":"2019-03-31T09:28:40Z",
        "formobject_id":"a5ec120cd61e41a2a8f05b01edbb8a89",
        "Region_2_name":["Maharashtra"],
        "Region_2":["a478ce4bcd7c441c8534849631bebaf8"],
}


In this document i have one field "Region_2" which contains one id "a478ce4bcd7c441c8534849631bebaf8" & this id is present in 208 other solr documents like,

{
        "form_id":26825,
        "form_object_id":"a478ce4bcd7c441c8534849631bebaf8",
        "title":"Maharashtra",
        "location.lat":0.0,
        "location.long":0.0,
        "created_date":"2019-03-31T09:27:55Z",
        "form_name":"Region",
        "type":"assetformobject",
        "id":"formobj_a478ce4bcd7c441c8534849631bebaf8_account_1704",
}
```

here form_object_id is same as that as "Region_2" field in previous documents.
when i join like,

```
{!join+from=Region_2+to=form_object_id}title:Mumbai
```

this query was supposed to return 208 documents but its return only 51 but when i started solr in single core same query return's all 208 results.
I think this may be because solr distribute documents across multiple shards.
Is there any way to do this in solr cloud?

Comment: As far as I know the documents has to be present on the same server for the join to succeed. You can use [Document Routing](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/6_6/shards-and-indexing-data-in-solrcloud.html#ShardsandIndexingDatainSolrCloud-DocumentRouting) to make sure related documents end up on the same shards. See if that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Yes , this is possible in solr cloud. 
Join is not possible if two documents are not in same shard.
For join to work, you have to save every linked document in same shard, in your case if both of these ducument get saved in same shard then join will work as we expect.

**Solution 1:**

Prefix your 'id' field with some common value followed by **"!"(exclamation mark)**. From the example above it looks like "account_1704" is something common between above doc.

If possible, create id something like "account_1704!_formobj_a5ec120cd61e41a2a8f05b01edbb8a89" and "account_1704!_formobj_a478ce4bcd7c441c8534849631bebaf8"
In this way these 2 docs will always fall in same shard (reason: Solr will consider string before ! for hash creation and created has for both docs will be same, so both docs will route in same shard)

If "id" manipulation is not possible then go for Solution 2

**Solution 2:**

While creating collection set **router.name** to **"implicit"** (default is compositeId) and **router.field to "form_object_id"** (as it is common between documents).
Then these documents will get stored in same shard and join will work.